# In what merit did Yosef become viceroy of Egypt?

Tags: yosef, miketz

What did Yosef Hatzadik do in his youth to merit becoming mishneh lamelech?

This is from a fourth grader's extra credit question, and the adults don't know the answer.

Comment: Welcome to the site, user18454! Is there a particular system of _sachar va'onesh_ that you are assuming as the basis of the question? Are you referring to a particular _midrash_? Filling in the background would make it a much stronger question and more likely to be met by a satisfying answer.

Comment: It's actually a fourth grader's extra credit and the adults don't know the answer. That's all the info we have!

Comment: Is it a [Breslever](https://www.breslev.co.il/articles/%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90_%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%99_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A2_%D7%95%D7%99%D7%92%D7%A9/%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A2/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A2.aspx?id=2453&language=hebrew) fourth grade? Maybe it was his natural ability that qualified him for the job (cf. _Yalkut Shim'oni_ [831](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.831.8?lang=he). It would still be helpful to edit in details.

Answer (score 2):

See Bereishis Rabba ([90:3](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%A6#%D7%92.)) where we learn that Yosef merited the glory of becoming viceroy, as a reward for successfully passing the tremendous test of withstanding the temptations of Potiphar's wife.

> ג ויאמר פרעה אל יוסף ויסר פרעה וגו'. א"ר שמעון בן גמליאל, יוסף משלו נתנו לו, פיו שלא נשק בעבירה "ועל פיך ישק כל עמי", גופו שלא נגע בעבירה "וילבש אותו בגדי שש", צוארו שלא הרכין לעבירה "וישם רביד הזהב על צוארו", ידיו שלא משמשו בעבירה "ויסר המלך את טבעתו מעל ידו ויתן אותה על יד יוסף", רגליו שלא פסעו בעבירה ייתון וירכבו על קרוכין "וירכב אותו במרכבת המשנה אשר לו", מחשבה שלא חשבה בעבירה תבא ותקרא חכמה "ויקראו לפניו אברך" אב בחכמה ורך בשנים

Yosef had an additional merit, in that he protected his mother, Rachel, from the gaze of his wicked uncle, Eisav. See Rashi (Bereishis [49:22, s.v. שור](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Bereshit/49/22#e0n6))

> בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁבָּא עֵשָׂו לִקְרַאת יַעֲקֹב, בְּכֻלָּן קָדְמוּ הָאִמָּהוֹת לָלֶכֶת לִפְנֵי בְּנֵיהֶם לְהִשְׁתַּחֲווֹת, וּבְרָחֵל כְּתִיב נִגַּשׁ יוֹסֵף וְרָחֵל וַיִּשְׁתַּחֲווּ, אָמַר יוֹסֵף רָשָׁע הַזֶּה עֵינוֹ רָמָה, שֶׁמָּא יִתֵּן עֵינָיו בְּאִמִּי, יָצָא לְפָנֶיהָ וְשִׁרְבֵּב קוֹמָתוֹ לְכַסּוֹתָהּ, וְהוּא שֶׁבֵּרְכוֹ אָבִיו בֵּן פֹּרָת – הִגְדַּלְתָּ עַצְמְךָ יוֹסֵף עֲלֵי עַיִן שֶׁל עֵשָׂו, לְפִיכָךְ זָכִיתָ לִגְדֻלָּה:

Comment: Thank you so much for this beautiful, clear answer with a source